# Simplex method Dual phase precision problem

Tags: algorithms, two-phase-simplex

I am trying to implement simplex method algorithm in PHP language. But I am facing with precision problem.

For example if I try to solve these equations:

```
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 >= 1 
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 >= 10 
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 >= 1 
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 >= 1 
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 >= 8 
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 >= 9 
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 >= 4 
28.46295 6.76625 32.8487 21.39885 1.41525 1.1381 2.5575 0 0 0 <= 375 
28.46295 6.76625 32.8487 21.39885 1.41525 1.1381 2.5575 0 0 0 >= 125 
17.2515 1.1718 24.8496 17.68302 0.093 0.10695 0.07905 0 0 0 <= 93.75 
17.2515 1.1718 24.8496 17.68302 0.093 0.10695 0.07905 0 0 0 >= 31.25 
6.61125 4.8667 3.81505 1.77735 0.984 0.83435 0.16605 0 0 0 <= 93.75 
6.61125 4.8667 3.81505 1.77735 0.984 0.83435 0.16605 0 0 0 >= 31.25 
4.6002 0.72775 4.18405 1.93848 0.33825 0.1968 2.3124 0 0 0 <= 187.5 
4.6002 0.72775 4.18405 1.93848 0.33825 0.1968 2.3124 0 0 0 >= 62.5 
17.2515 1.1718 24.8496 17.68302 0.093 0.10695 0.07905 1 0 0 >= 62.5 
17.2515 1.1718 24.8496 17.68302 0.093 0.10695 0.07905 -1 0 0 <= 62.5 
6.61125 4.8667 3.81505 1.77735 0.984 0.83435 0.16605 0 1 0 >= 62.5 
6.61125 4.8667 3.81505 1.77735 0.984 0.83435 0.16605 0 -1 0 <= 62.5 
4.6002 0.72775 4.18405 1.93848 0.33825 0.1968 2.3124 0 0 1 >= 125 
4.6002 0.72775 4.18405 1.93848 0.33825 0.1968 2.3124 0 0 -1 <= 125
```

and in few steps I am dealing with numbers like -2.2204460492503E-16 PHP is not capable to deal with very small number without an precision error...

So my question is, is there any point of calculation where I can for example round the numbers?
Because just working with bigger precision is not a solution (I think) because when we have a number 1/3 there is not enough space after decimal point....

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok well what I did and is working as solution is that after each elimination I check whole table and numbers which has absolute value  smaller then 0.000001 I set to 0....